# Display the statistical test + the number of individuals (n = ) with stat_compare_means()

Tags: r, ggplot2, comparison, boxplot

I currently use `stat_compare_means()` to display the comparison test on a boxplot with `ggplot2`. However, I would like the function to display the number of individuals (n = ) of the samples between the name of the test and the given p-value. Is there a way to add that information into `stat_compare_means()` ? I could easily display it with `geom_text()` or `annotate()`, but it isn't quite convenient since I want it to be written right before the p-value.

```
data(iris)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, shape=21, colour="black", fill="grey95", stroke=0.5, size=2) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y.npc = 0.93, method = "kruskal.test", size = 5, family = "serif") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: But there are 3 groups. How should the `n = ` be formatted? Do you want `Kruskall-Wallis, n = 50, 50, 50, p < 2.2e-16`? This wouldn't make sense to most readers. Shouldn't you have the n under each Species in the x axis? Or do you want the total number (e.g. n = 150)?

Comment: You're right. I thought that if the n is the same for each group, it would make sense to display it after the test. Would it be possible to display the total number then ?

Comment: Either something like this `Kruskal-Wallis (n = 150), p < 2.2e-16` or this `Kruskal-Wallis, n = 150, p < 2.2e-16`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could have the total `n` by adjusting the `label` aesthetic of `stat_compare_means`:

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "grey95", 
              stroke = 0.5, size = 2) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y.npc = 0.93, method = "kruskal.test", 
                     size = 5, family = "serif",
                     aes(label = paste0(after_stat(method), 
                                        ', n =', nrow(iris),
                                        after_stat(p.format)))) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Personally, I think it makes more sense to label the x axis with the number of observations in each group:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Species = paste0(Species, '\n(n = ', n(), ')')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +               
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, shape = 21, colour = "black", fill = "grey95", 
              stroke = 0.5, size = 2) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y.npc = 0.93, method = "kruskal.test", 
                     size = 5, family = "serif") +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16, base_family = 'serif')
```

[image]

Comment: It works. However, I get some problems with your second example if I add `geom_point()`or `geom_errorbar()`, for example, with another dataset called. In this case, the x axis groups are doubled, since `iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(Species = paste0(Species, '\n(n = ', n(), ')')) %>%` only refers to iris dataset. Any idea on what to adjust ?